Okta Integration - Throwing timeout error if not logged in to my admin account
I have integrated Okta with my web application for authenticate and authorization. I have a okta-dev (okta-dev-8*****4) account that I am using for integration.
If I login to okta-dev-8*****4 account on a separate browser window and then access the web app, It works fine. It asks for the credentials. On successful login, it take me back to the webapp.
If I do not login to okta-dev-8*****4 account on a separate browser window and then access the web app, it throws this error

Connecting to My Web App Sign in with your okta-dev-8*****4 account
to access My Web App
Powered by Okta
Privacy Policy
Okta The page has timed out If this page does not reload
automatically, please refresh your browser.

Here is my application 'grant type'

